# Can you use setKeepTogether in iText 7 for a 3rd layer nested table?

Tags: java, itext, itext7

I'm trying to use the setKeepTogether function in iText 7 in a nested table, but it doesn't seem to be working. So I have the following table structure:

[ Container [ Section [ Topic [ Topics Table ] ] ] ]

I'm trying to add the keepTogether function on the topics table but i am getting a index out of bounds exception:

```
    Unknown Excepion occurred : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 12, Size: 12
com.endeveran.common.exception.EndeveranException: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 12, Size: 12
    at com.endeveran.organ.OrgAnalyzer.run(OrgAnalyzer.java:419)
    at com.endeveran.organ.app.Organ.main(Organ.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 12, Size: 12
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.CollapsedTableBorders.getCellBorderIndents(CollapsedTableBorders.java:156)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableWidths.getCellBorderIndents(TableWidths.java:606)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableWidths.calculateMinMaxWidths(TableWidths.java:566)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableWidths.autoLayout(TableWidths.java:103)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableWidths.layout(TableWidths.java:92)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableRenderer.getMinMaxWidth(TableRenderer.java:1176)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.BlockRenderer.getMinMaxWidth(BlockRenderer.java:716)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableWidths.calculateMinMaxWidths(TableWidths.java:565)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableWidths.autoLayout(TableWidths.java:103)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableWidths.layout(TableWidths.java:92)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableRenderer.getMinMaxWidth(TableRenderer.java:1176)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.BlockRenderer.getMinMaxWidth(BlockRenderer.java:716)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableWidths.calculateMinMaxWidths(TableWidths.java:565)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableWidths.autoLayout(TableWidths.java:103)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableWidths.layout(TableWidths.java:92)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableRenderer.calculateColumnWidths(TableRenderer.java:1578)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableRenderer.layout(TableRenderer.java:266)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.addChild(RootRenderer.java:113)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.RootElement.add(RootElement.java:109)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.Document.add(Document.java:143)
    at
```

Comment: My main advice here would be to avoid nesting tables. Nesting tables is always tricky, it always incurs a performance penalty, and it makes the document (and the code generating it) needlessly complex.

Comment: Please add the code you used to generate the table.